# Wildcard *.local hosts to apache on OS X

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, hosts, local

I would like to route all my *.local or *.dev domains to a specific IP, either the IP of my Ubuntu VM or localhost. Is this possible?  Can I use the /etc/hosts file?

I am running Mac OS X Snow Leopard with Ubuntu Hardy Heron LTS - JeOS on VMware Fusion 3.

Right now I just keep making /etc/hosts records for each one and I would rather it be like wildcard DNS and let Apache handle the domains then manually entering it each time.  I like the flexibility to update this when I do something odd or someone gives me a strange request but 90% of it I think would be best automated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not add wildcard entries to /etc/hosts file. That being said [This Article](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=2005110220352084) demonstrates a method that works with Tiger. Although I think launchctl is deprecated as of leopard but it may still work.

Comment: thanks, I got it setup with this link as well jumping between them both: http://geoffhankerson.com/node/108

Comment: This one also helped and was more consolidated than jumping from one to the other: http://grahamweldon.com/blog/wildcard-subdomains-for-quick-virtual-host-creation

Answer (score 0):

Setting-up the wildcard response in the apache configs is straightforward, but apache has nothing to do with your local name resolution - it only accepts connections that have been handed to it, so it's up to the network stack to direct the connection in the proper direction first.

As far as I know, this means you need to either be running a local DNS server on your network/machine, or you need to add entries in /etc/hosts for every dev domain.

Answer (score 0):

Run something like dnsmasq, which will let you add a few custom DNS entries, but forward everything else to your normal DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

We setup the BIND DNS-server on a linux machine to point the *.dev TLD to an Apache machine. We advertise this DNS-server to all LAN clients via DHCP, so all requests go through this server and can resolve .dev.

In the Apache config we're using so-called mass-virtual-hosting to avoid having to edit the config for every new site. This way we can simply create a new directory with the correct naming convention and it will be found.

Comment: I am working local, from Snow Leopard to Ubuntu VM, is there a reasonable setup for Bind on Snow Leopard?